# Is Operation Id unique?

Tags: operations, payments

I am confusing about operation id. Is it unique within the network or within a transaction?

In other words, will it be enough to store only OperationId in DB or should the Primary Key be a complex (TransactionId + OperationId)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OperationId is unique within the network, so you need not to pair it with TransactionId. (TransactionId is also known as TransactionHash.)

You may consider OperationId a better choice for primary key, if the transactions contain more than one operation.

> The operation details endpoint provides information on a single operation. The operation ID provided in the id argument specifies which operation to load.
>   https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/operations-single.html

Example: https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/operations/0002168464563249153

The Horizon `operations` endpoint returns just one operation (if found).